# Excel VBA textbox password protected

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way in which I can make the text box password protected in excel VBA. I want to make the contents of the textbox password protected so that if anyone one wants to change the values of the text box, it asks them the password.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of text box are you using? Can you show us the code that calls the textbox.

Comment: Is the textbox on a sheet or a userform?  If on a sheet, is it a forms control or an ActiveX control?

Comment: Use the GotFocus event to ask the password and if it does not match choose a random cell.

Comment: Your question is too broad to be a good for for this site. You need to at least *try*, hit a roadbumb, and ask about that specific problem you're encountering, showing us your code and what's failing where - see [mcve]. FWIW the answer to your question as asked, is "Yes, there's a way." - boring huh?

Comment: @tigeravatar This is the textbox on the sheet with ActiveX control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified "This is the textbox on the sheet with ActiveX control"

In that sheet's code module, enter this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()

    Dim Password As String

    Password = InputBox("Enter password to edit this field:", "Password")
    If Password <> "MyPassword123" Then Me.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

If you want the password box to be `***`'s so that the password is masked when users type it, you will need to create a userform with a textbox and have its `PasswordChar` property set to `*`.  Then you'd call the userform and have it perform the password check.

Comment: If the text box is already disabled then is there a way to fire the event?

Comment: @Ninja No, you'd have to enable the textbox first.